# Getting "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" in BIRT report

Tags: birt, spagobi

I am getting "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" in BIRT report (SPAGO BI) on IE9. SPAGO BI version is 3.4. My reports were working fine and they stopped without any change by me. Wondering if someone else got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse - > Windows - > Preferences - > Report Design - >Preview - >Preview Server and type 'localhost' or server ip in first tab 
If it still does not work, it could be that another service is using the default port. You can manually assign a port number (9097).